# Angular Material suddenly stopped working for me

Tags: angular, angular-material

(Please note that I am completely new to Angular, this only being my third week working with it)

I was trying to use the following list of commands to use custom SVG icons in Angular material:

```bash
mkdir angular-material-custom-svg
cd angular-material-custom-svg
npm install @angular/cli@10.0.4 --save-dev
ng new angular-material-custom-svg --directory=. --skipTests=true --routing=false --style=css
npm install @angular/material@10.1.1 @angular/cdk@10.1.1 --save
```

And then suddenly, the rest of all of my Angular Material stopped working. For each one, I get the following error:

[image: The errors shown when I hover over the imports in my app.module.ts]

I have been going through my package.json and package-lock.json to try to figure out where the version mismatches are.

Here is my `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "frontier-website",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.0",
    "igniteui-theming": "^1.4.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.2.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.6.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

I have tried all the ng commands, such as ng update and so on to try to get everything to sync up. So far, I have had no luck with Google or Discord when searching for information about my problem.

Comment: You are 6 versions late for Angular. This makes the problem difficult to reproduce. If `ng update` is too complex (which is understandable when you are late by several versions), you can try to create a new project and copy the `src` directory